# Java Object serialization in scala

Tags: scala, apache-spark

Pardon me as I am new to Scala. 
I have created a case class which encapsultes some information. One of the objects i want to take in for that is of JavaClass. As i am using in spark, i would need it to be serializable. How can i do that?

Java class

```
public class Currency {

    public Currency(final BigDecimal amount, final CurrencyUnit unit) {
        //Doing Something
    }
}

case class ReconEntity(inputCurrency : Currency, outputCurrency : Currency)
```

Using implicit i want to have my serialization code for Currency so that spark can work on ReconEntity.

Comment: Just add this: public class Currency extends Serializable

Comment: That looks like an answer to me.

Comment: @bupt_ljy, i do not own that class, So can't make changes

Answer (score 1):

Firstly, have you tried some RDD operations using your `Currency` and `ReconEntity` classes? Do you actually get an error? Spark is able to handle RDD operations with apparently non-serializable Scala classes as values, at least (you can try this in the `spark-shell`, though possibly this might require the [Kryo serializer](https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/tuning.html#data-serialization) to be enabled).

Since you state that you don't own the `Currency` class, you can't add `extends Serializable`, which would be the simplest solution.

Another approach is to wrap the class with a serializable wrapper, as described in this article: [Beating Serialization in Spark](https://gist.github.com/kmader/1d64e64621e63d566f67) - example code copied here for convenience:

> For simple classes, it is easiest to make a wrapper interface that
>   extends Serializable. This means that even though UnserializableObject
>   cannot be serialized we can pass in the following object without any
>   issue

```
public interface UnserializableWrapper extends Serializable {
  public UnserializableObject create(String prm1, String prm2);
}
```

> The object can then be passed into an RDD or Map function using the
>   following approach

```
UnserializableWrapper usw = new UnserializableWrapper() {
  public UnserializableObject create(String prm1, String prm2) {
    return new UnserializableObject(prm1,prm2);
} }
```

If the  class is merely a data structure, without significant methods, then it might be easier to unpack its fields into your RDD types (in your case, `ReconEntity`) and discard the class itself.

If the class has methods that you need, then your other (ugly) option is to cut-and-paste code into a new serializable class or into helper functions in your Spark code.